# Wallpapers other than default are not appearing as background after restart

Tags: desktop-background

I'm using Ubuntu 10.04 alongside Windows 7. If I change the wallpaper to anything other than the default, after restarting the system, my screen remains completely black..

Answer (score 1):

It might be because the system cannot find/access the selected wallpaper after restart (due to folder/file permissions or unmounted partition, etc.?), maybe you can try copying/moving it to user-specific or system-wide folder for wallpapers (e.g. `/home/you/.wallpapers`, `/usr/share/wallpapers`, or "backgrounds" or something like this)?
Alternatively, if you cannot get more or better answers, you may perhaps consider upgrading to the current Ubuntu version unless you have a good reason not to do so.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is

1. Copy the file to your Home directory (partition of Ubuntu)
2. Give 700 permission to that image you are using with the command

   ```
   chmod 700 filename
   ```

It won't change when you restart.